# Accordion - add/remove loading class on css transition (timing issue)

Tags: jquery, css, settimeout, transitionend

I'm building an accordion where I'm toggling each accordion-fold on click. The javascript toggles a class while the css takes care of the animation.

When the accordion-fold is transitioning (expands or contracts) I want to set all the accordion-folds opacity to 1. When the css transition is complete I want to reset the opacity to the previous value but with a slight delay to avoid any flicker.

I've been trying to figure out how to do this using *transitionend* and *setTimeout* but the timing has been totally off. Any ideas appreciated. My code so far:

HTML:

```
<div class="accordion">

    <div class="accordion__fold">
        <img src="img/concept.jpg" alt="Concept" class="accordion__fold-image">
        <div class="accordion__fold-overlay accordion__fold-overlay--concept"></div>
        <div class="accordion__fold-inner">
            <img class="accordion__fold-icon" src="img/icons/lightbulb.svg" alt="Lightbulb">
            <h3 class="accordion__fold-heading">Concept</h3>
            <p class="accordion__fold-sub-heading">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</p>
        </div>
        <button class="btn accordion__fold-btn">Read more</button>
    </div>

    <div class="accordion__fold">
        <img src="img/ux.jpg" alt="UX/UI" class="accordion__fold-image">
        <div class="accordion__fold-overlay accordion__fold-overlay--ux"></div>
        <div class="accordion__fold-inner">
            <img class="accordion__fold-icon" src="img/icons/penn.svg" alt="Penn">
            <h3 class="accordion__fold-heading">UX/UI</h3>
            <p class="accordion__fold-sub-heading">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</p>
        </div>
        <button class="btn accordion__fold-btn">Read more</button>
    </div>

    <div class="accordion__fold">
        <img src="img/code.jpg" alt="Code" class="accordion__fold-image">
        <div class="accordion__fold-overlay accordion__fold-overlay--code"></div>
        <div class="accordion__fold-inner">
            <img class="accordion__fold-icon" src="img/icons/code.svg" alt="Code">
            <h3 class="accordion__fold-heading">Code</h3>
            <p class="accordion__fold-sub-heading">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</p>
        </div>
        <button class="btn accordion__fold-btn">Read more</button>
    </div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
.accordion__fold--active {
    flex-grow: 8;
}

.accordion__fold-overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0.95;
  transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
}

.accordion--loading .accordion__fold-overlay {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Javascript:

```
const $accordion = $('.accordion');
const $folds = $('.accordion__fold');

$folds.each((index, fold) => {
    const $this = $(fold);

    $this.on('click', () => {

        // toggle active fold
        $folds.not($this).removeClass('accordion__fold--active');
        $this.toggleClass('accordion__fold--active');

        // set loading class
        $accordion.addClass('accordion--loading');

        $this.on('transitionend', () => {

            // remove loading class (timing is often off)
            setTimeout(() => {
                $accordion.removeClass('accordion--loading');
            }, 250);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: can you show the html too?

Comment: @Kiwad Updated my question.